# Microsoft teams staticTabs to page in Azure with OAuth AAD authorization

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams

I created a basic demo custom app for microsoft teams from the MS repository https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v1.0.0/hello-world-tab . I added additional static tabs to my already existing page in azure (application hosted on Azure is secured via AAD). In the app manifest
{
"entityId": "0000002",
"name": "NameOfApp",
"contentUrl": "https://nameofapp.azurewebsites.net",
"websiteUrl": "https://nameofapp.azurewebsites.net",
"scopes": [
"personal".
]
},

The problem is that the application somehow manages to authorise itself to the protected application when I launch it via the browser, but I get an error when I open it via the desktop application

Error message : Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

How can I authorise in PC applications MS Teams ?

Comment: Have you followed the prerequisites of tab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

Comment: You'll need to use `authentication.authenticate` API and the flow outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab

Comment: My page using redirect for login @Nivedipa-MSFT so how can I make it without changing website already hosted on azure. I can apply changes only in new teams app

Answer (score 1):

**Login pages don't render in iFrames, as a safeguard against clickjacking.**

Your authentication logic needs to use a method other than redirect. For example, use token-based or cookie-based authentication.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements